# Spring Boot filter order: WebLogic 12c vs Tomcat 8

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security, spring-boot, weblogic

I'm writing a web application in Spring Boot that has a filter that must execute **after** spring's security filters.

I've configured my filter chain via java config, and have set my custom filter's order to a value higher than spring security's. This works as expected when running the application on Tomcat; however, this doesn't work in WebLogic 12c. WebLogic executes the filter chain in reverse of how Tomcat executes it (and/or vice versa).

Has anyone encountered this peculial quirk before? Is there a way to make WebLogic behave as Tomcat does?

My code:

```
final FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(new MyFilter());
registration.setOrder(-99); // spring security's is -100
```

On Tomcat, this MyFilter fires after the security filters. In WebLogic, MyFilter fires before the security filters. If I change the value of `setOrder` to -101, say, then it will work for WebLogic but not for Tomcat.

I would like to run the application on both app servers, depending on context, so I need to figure out how to make this work.

Comment: I think I've seen this before and it turned out to be a bug in Weblogic

Comment: Pass the setOrder value as profile based parameter to workaround the issue? profile-localhost' is tomcat verse profile-uat is weblogic.

Comment: Hey Brian. My team has long since moved on from WebLogic, but the fix we eventually settled on is similar to your suggestion.. we simply defined a flag, `application.fix-weblogic-filter-order=true` that reversed the order of the entire filter stack at startup. Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a bug in WebLogic: "20493506 : WLS 12.1.2 - Servlet 3 addFilter adds filters in wrong order".

The Spring Boot team were [made aware of this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2643) over a year ago. Unfortunately, there's nothing that Spring Boot can do about it. Hopefully 15 months plus is long enough for Oracle to have shipped a fix that you can apply to your Weblogic installation.

Comment: Thanks. https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1996257.1, for anyone with an oracle support account.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the patch is available or our ops team hasn't applied it, but it's still broken for us. [This](https://gist.github.com/bernerbrau/415139e8e51ff1845daba7ff241e08d7) is the solution I came up with.